# Best way to add new tag to existing registered device (FCM, Xamarin.Forms, c#)

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Sorry ahead of time as I'm at work so I don't have all my code in front of me that I could post here.

I'm wanting to figure out the best way to add a new tag to an existing registered device in FCM. Basically I have a Xamarin.Forms app with push notifications implemented. The question was brought up about what happens if a user logs into the app from a different device. How would you add a new tag (or the tag associated with that user) to the device so they can receive the notifications that are associated with them while they're logged in?

I started looking at some of the rest API's in the documentation (again...sorry I don't have the link to it) and it looks like there's one API where its "create/update device registration" and it basically takes a tag(s) and the gcm registration id (I think).

My thought was that I could pull the already registered device id and use that to update the registration with a new tag using the Rest API. **What does the c# code look like to pull the existing registration id?**

I've been trying to use the `FirebaseInstanceId.GetInstance().GetInstanceId().GetToken` (pseudo from memory) but I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly.

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: In my opinion, each user has a Unique id and this can be use as the tag when you send the specific notifications. After the user login, you can send this id to your app server and your server side can choose to push notification to those users with the ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found the answer to my own question in the form of `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties` found [here](https://codemilltech.com/persist-whatever-you-want-with-xamarin-forms/).

I tested with the approach of storing the gcm registered id (token) in the properties dictionary after the initial token creation. I then closed the app, re-opened it and verified that the token value persisted and I was able to retrieve the value so I could then use it in the API calls.

Comment: You can mark it as the right answer which will help more people with same problem:).